# (Python) What easiest way to detect whether an optional argument is actually passed to function?

Tags: python, arguments, option-type

A function in Python:

```
def f(a=1):
  print(a)
```

What easiest way to detect whether the argument «*a*» is actually passed to *f* or is missed?

There is a function «*IsMissing*» in VBA:

```
IsMissing(argname)
```

Does anything similar exist in Python?

---

I mean something like this:

```
def f(a=1):
  …
  …


f()
>>> The argument «a» was not passed!
f(1)
>>> The argument «a» was passed and is equal to: 1
```

Comment: You can tell if something other than `1` was passed by checking the value.  There is no way to distinguish between explicitly passing the default value and and getting it "by default" when it is not passed.